Link between the directional derivative of a vector field and connection
I am learning about connection in my differential geometry course. I am trying to map the familiar concepts such as "differential", "directional derivative", "gradient" and "connection" from calculus to geometry. As far as I have understood, for a function $F: M \to N$ between manifolds, $dF$ is the differential from calculus, while the value $dF_p(v)$ corresponds to the directional derivative $D_v F$ from calculus.
Now looking at the vector field $Z: M \to TM$, we use connections $\nabla_v Z$ to generalise directional derivatives to vector fields (because we cannot "connect" unrelated tangent spaces). But what about $dZ: TM \to TTM$? Shouldn't there be a link between $\nabla_v Z$ and $dZ_p(v)$? I understand that these are two different objects, but both convey the idea of the directional derivative, don't they?

Have you tried writing this out in coordinates? Note that $\nabla_v Z(p)$ requires a connection and $dZ_p(v)$ does not. $\nabla_v Z(p)\in T_pM$, whereas $dZ_p(v)\in T_{(p,Z(p))}TM$.

Let $(E,\pi,M)$ be a vector bundle.  First recall that for each $u\in E_p$, we have $V_uE=T_u(E_p)=\ker(T\pi_u)$, i.e the vertical space is the tangent space of the fiber. In our present case, the fiber is itself a vector space, so the tangent space can be canonically identified with itself; for definiteness call this isomorphism $\iota_{p,u}:E_p\to V_uE$.
Now, Ehresmann's definition of a connection is much more geometric than simply specifying a differential operator $\nabla$: he defines a connection to be a choice of a certain complementary subbundle $HE$ to the vertical subbundle $VE\subset TE$. Relative to the decomposition $TE=VE\oplus HE$, we have the two induced direct sum projections $P_V:TE\to VE$ and $P_H:TE\to HE$.
Now, given a section $\sigma:M\to E$, by fixing $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$, we get an element $(T\sigma_p)(v)\in T_{\sigma(p)}E$. This vector can be decomposed into two pieces:
\begin{align}
T\sigma_p(v)=P_V\left(T\sigma_p(v)\right)+ P_H\left(T\sigma_p(v)\right)\in V_{\sigma(p)}E\oplus H_{\sigma(p)}E.
\end{align}
For the vertical component, let us define $\nabla_v\sigma:=\iota_{p,\sigma(p)}^{-1}\left((P_V\circ T\sigma)_p(v)\right)\in E_{p}$. So, this is the relationship between the differential operator $\nabla$ and the projection $P_V$ (which is equivalent to specifying the complementary subbundle $HE=\ker(P_V)$).
So, once again,
\begin{align}
\nabla_v\sigma\cong P_V(T\sigma_p(v))= T\sigma_p(v)-P_H(T\sigma_p(v)),
\end{align}
or in words, $\nabla_v\sigma$ is identified with a certain vertical projection of $T\sigma_p(v)$. In local coordinates, we see this super clearly in the formula $(\nabla_v\sigma)^i=v^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}\sigma^i+\Gamma_{\alpha j}^iv^{\alpha}\sigma^j$. Notice how in local coordinates, the covariant derivative is obtained by adding some extra piece to the naive $\partial$ term. Classically, one would say this extra piece is precisely what is needed to offset things so that we have the 'right transformation law'. Well, now we can interpret this term more geometrically as being the thing added so as to project the full vector $T\sigma_p(v)$ onto the vertical subspace.
Note that the presence of a connection is needed because if want our 'directional derivative' to still take values in $E$, rather than the larger space $TE$.

While $\nabla_v(Z)$ describes the change of the vector field $Z$ in the directon $v$ along the manifold, $dZ$ describes how the vector field $Z$ varies in the total space. We can think of $dZ$ as a way to lift vector fields from the base space to the total space of the tangent bundle $TM$. So, for a point $p \in M$ and a vector $v \in T_pM$ the map $dZ_p(v) \in T_{(p,Z(p))}TM$ describes how the vector field $Z$ changes at the point  $(p,Z(p))$ in the direction $v$ both along the manifold as well as across the fibers of the tangent bundle.
An analogous idea would be to consider a hypersurface $S$ embedded in a Euclidean space. We can differentiate some vector along a direction $v$ on the surface in two ways; Covariant differentiation or Total differentiation. For the former we have;
$$\nabla_v(Z)=v^i\big[\partial_i(Z^j)+Z^m\Gamma^{j}_{im}\big]e_j$$
while the latter yields;
$$dZ(v)=v^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(Z^me_m)=v^i\big[\partial_i(Z^j)+Z^m\Gamma^{j}_{im}\big]e_j+v^iZ^mB_{im}\hat{n}$$
$$=\nabla_{v}Z+v^iZ^mB_{im}\hat{n}$$
Where $B_{im}$ is the second fundamental form for your embedded hypersurface and $\hat{n}$ is the unit normal. So the covariant derivative of our vector field along the direction $v$ is simply the tangential component of the overall change in the ambient space. Similarly, $\nabla_vZ$ is simply the projection of the overall change of the vector field $Z$ in the tangent bundle projected down to the base manifold $M$.
